# Clasificar por rango

Tags: php

tengo el siguiente problema. Tengo un array de números, otro de limiteInferior y otro de limiteSuperior. Muestro un ejemplo:

`$numeros = (1,4,2,3,5,9,7,6,8); $marcas = ("a", "b", "c", "d"); $limiteInferior = (0, 2, 5, 8); $limiteSuperior = (1, 4, 7, 9);`

Agrupando los 2 arrays de límites, tengo que los rangos son a de [0,1], b de [2,4], c de [5,7] y d de [8,9].

Lo que quiero es generar un nuevo array que me diga a qué marca pertenece cada número, sería así:

`$nuevoArray = ("a", "b", "b", "b", "c", "d", "c", "c", "d");`

Lo pensé, pero no se me ocurren ideas.

El lenguaje es PHP

Gracias

Comment: Comienza por un ciclo para recorrer cada número.

Comment: No entendí tu pregunta, *a qué marca pertenece cada número* ¿qué quiere decir?

Comment: no entiendo del todo cual es el resultado que esperas, por favor si pudieras hacerlo mas especifico

Comment: El resultado que quiero llegar es generar un nuevo vector o array  con las marcas a las que pertenecen los números. Ésos rangos también deberían ser dinámicos. Es decir, si el rango a es [0,1] y el rango b es [2,4] y los números sos 1, 3, 0, 4, el nuevo array debería ser [a, b, a, b]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que la mejor forma seria crear un array asociativo donde la calve sea la *etiqueta* ("a", "b" o "c") de esta forma creo que será mucho mas fácil.

**¿Qué es un array asociativo?**
Los array asociativos son aquellos que se componen de una *clave* (o *key*) y un *valor*, la *clave* puede ser un string o un numero y el valor puede ser cualquier tipo de dato (array, string, int, boolean, etc). Se puede pensar en ellos de la forma en que la *clave* esta asociada al *valor* donde si queremos acceder al valor tendremos que hacerlo mediante su *clave*. Ejemplo.

```php
//creamos un array llamado animales
$animales = array(
    // clave     valor
    "perro" => "michi",
    "gato" => "firulais"
);
```

Para acceder a un elemento lo hacemos mediante su *clave* (o *key*), de esta forma.

```php
//accedemos mediante la clave con comillas "perro"
echo($animales["perro"])
//salida -> "michi"
```

**Comenzamos**
Primero comenzaremos a iterar en los números, posteriormente en los rangos.

```php
<?php
$numeros = [0,8,4,5,2,1,9,3];
//array asociativo
$rangos = ["a"=>[0,2], "b"=>[3,5], "c"=>[6,9]];

//aqui se almacenaran los resultados 
$result = [];

//recorremos los numeros
for ($i = 0; $i < count($numeros); $i++) {
    //recorremos los rangos
    foreach ($rangos as $key => $val){
        $ini = $val[0];
        $fin = $val[1];
        //verificamos si esta en el rango
        if(($ini<$numeros[$i]) && ($numeros[$i]<=$fin)){
            //key nos devuelve la clave del array
            echo("$numeros[$i] se encuentra en el rango, etiquetada como $key\n");
            //agregamos al array
            $result[$i] = $key;
        }
    }
}
//imprimimos el array
print_r($result);
?>
```

**Produce**

```
8 se encuentra en el rango, etiquetada como c
4 se encuentra en el rango, etiquetada como b
5 se encuentra en el rango, etiquetada como b
2 se encuentra en el rango, etiquetada como a
1 se encuentra en el rango, etiquetada como a
9 se encuentra en el rango, etiquetada como c

Array
(
    [1] => c
    [2] => b
    [3] => b
    [4] => a
    [5] => a
    [6] => c
)
```

Hace tiempo no trabajo con este lenguaje, por lo que talvez exista una mejor forma de hacerlo.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta. Ahora ése array de "rangos" debería ser dinámico. Ésa parte debería ver cómo implementarla

Comment: como "dinamico"? si tienes una duda realiza otra pregunta agregando lo que ya haz probado, y si la respuesta te sirvió acéptala

Comment: Dinámico me refiero a que los rangos pueden variar, en el ejemplo mostré 4 rangos, pero pueden haber más

Comment: Simplemente añade los rangos al array asociativo `"d"=>[11,13]` y el código seguirá funcionando

Comment: Gracias, voy a revisar e investigar un poco de éso, sería una matriz, o un array de arrays

Comment: se llama array asociativo ya que tiene una *clave* que se asocia a un valor, voy a editar la respuesta añadiendo una explicacion

Comment: Edite mi respuesta añadiendo una breve explicacion

Comment: Muchísimas gracias. Lo pondré en práctica. No puedo votar la respuesta porque soy nuevo x acá 

Comment: votar a favor es diferente de aceptarla, una respuesta se acepta con un "check" que hay debajo de los votos, una respuesta se acepta cuando esta resolvió tu problema, esto recompensa a ambas partes, eso depende de ti. puedes ver [esta publicacion](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/427/c%C3%B3mo-funciona-la-aceptaci%C3%B3n-de-respuestas)

Comment: Ahí está. No sabía. Soy nuevo x acá. Saludos